# My prefix is from a hide, my suffix is groom or bride

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My prefix is from a hide,
>
> My suffix is groom or bride.
>
> My infix is old until...
>
> I am gross but also fill.

Hint 1:

> What eats gross food?

Hint 2:

> You can find me in a shed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New Answer

> **FERTILIZER**

My prefix is from a hide,

> **FER** - FUR comes from a hide

My suffix is groom or bride.

> **ZER** - Non-gender specific way of saying Ma'am or Sir

My infix is old until...

> **TIL** - TILL could be an old way of saying UNTIL

I am gross but also fill.

> Fertilizer is gross but fills the ground with nutrients needed to grow vegetation.

Hint

> We can use compost to fertilize gardens, found in a shed.

Previous Answer

> **GARB-AGE-MAN**

Comment: Not it. You're on thee right track though.